# CSS float two colums from inside the content to the left and right

Tags: css

What I'm trying to achieve looks like the picture below. Mind the number is the order of each box in the HTML. I don't wish to change the order as it's the order I wish to have for mobile view.
[image]

Box 2 and 3 and fixed width and the center ones are fluid.
What I've done so far can be seen on http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wBWPoB
and my problem is that using my solution I have to know the height of the box1 and I don't want to depend on it. **Box1 can become much higher and then it'll be hiding box4.**

Any ideas?

Please mind I've also tried to use `position: absolute` for box3 but then box6 will hide parts of it as box3 goes out of the layout completely.

Comment: [Sounds like a job for flexbox.](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Answer (score 0):

See the output below i tried to make it like your desired out put

- Clearing 1st and 6th from both side
- Float 3rd,4th,5th to left and making third larger than 4th and 5th
- Float 2nd one to right

```css
body{
   text-align:center;
   width:100%;
}
div{
width:400px;
  height:100px;
  background:red;
  margin-top:5px;
}
div:nth-child(3){
background:green;
  float:left;
  width:100px;
  height:500px;
}
div:nth-child(2){
background:green;
  float:right;
  width:100px;
  height:500px;
}

div:nth-child(6),div:nth-child(1){
background:yellow;
  clear:both;
 width:100%
  
}
div:nth-child(4),div:nth-child(5){
width:260px;
  float:left;
 margin:5px auto;

  
}
```

```html
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
<div>6</div>
```

Comment: Running the code snippet here, this isn't what I needed, see my attached picture.

Comment: let me see @Collector

Answer (score 0):

The solution (doesn't work well on IE yet) is to use padding instead of margin to get the side columns and then float all boxes. You can see the solution on http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ogLqwa - on IE you'll notice box4 is under box3 even though it should have been adjuscent to box1.

IMPORTANT: note that .one MUST have a border so it doesn't collapse. In the example, all divs have a border so you could notice them easily but without it, it will collapse.

A good friend helped me, guess something it's better than StackOverflow ;)

```css
div { font-size: 30px; border: 2px solid black; }
.container { border: 1px solid transparent; padding-left: 320px; padding-right: 220px;}
.one {height:200px; background: orange; float: left; width: 100%; margin-right: -100%; border: 1px solid black; }
.two { float: right; width: 200px; margin-right: -220px; height: 200px; }
.three { float: left; width: 300px; height: 300px; margin-left: -320px; }
.four {float: left;  width: 100%; background: red; }
.five {float: left;  width: 100%; background: red; }
.six { clear: both; width: 100%; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="one">1</div>
 <div class="two">2</div>
 <div class="three">3</div>
 <div class="four">4</div>
 <div class="five">5</div>
</div>
<div class="six">6</div>
```

Comment: As no good solution that would work on IE was found, I resorted to using `position:absolute` for the two side columns and set the container height to something pretty large. The jQuery kicks in when the DOM is ready and adjusts the container height. I would have liked a CSS-only solution but for now, none seems to work in all situations on all browsers.